# 18.04 Ubuntu reboots after few seconds on shutdown command

Tags: reboot

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 lts on my laptop lenevo g560 1.8 gb ram. After update and few days of use, the laptop reboots even on shutdown.i have tried laptop mode install but to no use.please help

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. To get more help, you need to include details of your system and steps that you did. Also needed to include the relevant part of the log when you initiaited the shutdown from `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog`. Edit and update these to your original question, cheers.

Comment: system details are lenovo g560 laptop. Memory 1.8 gb. Processor Intel pentium CPU P6200 @ 2.13 Ghz x 2. Genome 3.28.2. I have installed laptop mode tools,i.e., sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools @ Bernard Wei

Comment: Try `shutdown -h now -t 0` to see that power off the machine.

Comment: Installed Ubuntu mate